# C# as operator on Type with generics but irrelevant <T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract base class with generics, I will simplify it for this question:

```
public abstract class DBBaseTable<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }     
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I can have classes like: `Person : DBBaseTable<int>` or `Animal: DBBaseTable<Guid>`

I am trying to avoid reflection in order to access the property RowVersion in a part of the code where I simply do not know the `T` Type.

```
var memberInfo = oldObject.GetType().BaseType;
if (memberInfo != null 
    && memberInfo.IsGenericType
    && memberInfo.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DBBaseTable<>)
)
{   
    var isCorrectRowVersion = (oldObject as DBBaseTable<object>).RowVersion ==
                              (objToUpdate as DBBaseTable<object>).RowVersion;

    //TODO....  
}
```

The conditional IF condition is working fine... but then when I try to use the `as` operator I always need to specify the `T` type... I have tried to use "object" but it is not working... and I simply do not know if I am dealing with int, guid or some other type....

I know how to solve this with reflection, but I would like to know if there is an alternative?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move the `RowVersion` into a base class.

```
public abstract DBBaseTable
{
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DBBaseTable<T> : DBBaseTable
{
    public T Id { get; set; }     
}
```

Comment: Great answer, this is also how IEnumerable does it.

Comment: (You could also use an interface which has `RowVersion` on it, and implement that in `DBBaseTable<T>`)

Comment: @canton7 - Yes, but then you'd have to implement it everywhere. Given that the question defined a base class it makes more sense to add another base class and only do the implementation once.

Comment: @Sean They've both got advantages and disadvantages. Using an interface avoids needing to chain through to a base constructor, for example. You can't say whether one approach is better than the other without more details of the use-case, which is why I added it as an additional option in brackets. I don't see why you'd need to implement an interface in any more locations than a base class, though?

Comment: You can easily and objectively show whether _"one approach is better than the other"_ because only one approach (interfaces) will lead to **decoupling** the _contract from the implementation_ as evidenced by _[static code analysis tools](https://www.ndepend.com/)_.  Not so with abstract classes being referred to everywhere

Comment: @MickyD Don't blindly trust your tools without understanding what's actually going on. A base class which behaves as an interface is often no worse than an interface

Comment: I understood the concept way before the tool existed thank-you.  Also, considering C# is rather limited on the number of base classes one can derive from at once, I'd much rather a lightweight interface

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to declare a base interface with `RowVersion` property and implement it in `DBBaseTable<T>` base class

```cs
public interface IDBTable
{
    byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DBBaseTable<T> : IDBTable
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public class Person : DBBaseTable<int>
{
    //rest of logic
}
```

Then you can access a `RowVersion` property without a cast

```cs
var isCorrectRowVersion = oldObject.RowVersion == objToUpdate.RowVersion;
```

With interfaces you are allowed to use [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) in generic types.

Also, you can implement multiple interfaces in one class, but inherit only one base class in `DBBaseTable<T>`. If you'll need to extend it in future, using an interface is preferable, IMO. But final decision depends on your needs.